# How do I combine a list with the elements of another list in R?

Tags: r

I know there is a simple function for this, but I can't find it anywhere. I have:

```
a <- list(a=1,b=2)
b <- list(c=3,d=4)
c <- list(e=5,f=6)
```

I want a list with 4 elements, list a, list b and the components of list c:

```
list(list(a=1, b=2), list(c=3, d=4), e = 5, f = 6)
```

Comment: wow, thanks, that was totally on my blind spot, you can add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `c` operator:

```
c(list(a,b), c)
```